# How to multiply decimal numbers without using multiplication(*) sign

Tags: c#

Can anyone suggest me a way to multiply decimal numbers without using multiplication(*) sign.
I know it looks like homework thing, but I just want to know how to achieve this. I have already done this for positive and negative integers as below:

```
int first = 2;
int second =2;
int result = 0;
bool isNegative = false;

if (first < 0)
{
    first = Math.Abs(first);
    isNegative = true;
}
if (second < 0)
{
    second = Math.Abs(second);
    isNegative = true;
}

for (int i = 1; i <= second; i++)
{
    result += first;
}

if (isNegative)
    result = -Math.Abs(result);
```

Want to multiply this for decimals:

```
decimal third = 1.1;
decimal fourth = 1.2;
```

Thanks

Comment: (-2)*(-2) = -4?

Comment: Out of curiouristy, what are you trying to do that this is a requirement?

Comment: With @Scott. Explain **why** you want to do this, or this question is only useful as _"see what clever code I can come up with"_ showcase. Are you trying to learn certain concepts, or tackle a larger problem?

Comment: Rather than as repeated add, you could use a bitwise multiplication as discussed here: http://ericlippert.com/2013/09/30/math-from-scratch-part-four/?utm_source=rss&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=math-from-scratch-part-four

Comment: Thanks for your answers and comments. just curious to know what (*) does at backend in .NET and also want to learn some programming :)

Comment: @user1211185 Knowing how the .NET framework implements multiplication is an entirely different question than asking people to provide any old multiplication implementation.

Comment: If you want to know the underlying algorithm used by floating point processors, check here: http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/BinMath/multFloat.html (but this is a generalised algorithm for floating point, not necessarily the one used for the decimal type)

Comment: @MatthewWatson thanks, I will have a look

Comment: @user1211185 - Well, the "backend" will at some point call [FCallMultiply](http://dotnetinside.com/en/framework/v4.0.30319/mscorlib/Decimal) and you won't get much deeper than that. Since in the end it's all about ones and zeros, you might want to read up on [binary multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_multiplier). You want to learn programming (that's good!); one very important lesson is: don't reinvent the wheel! Trust that `*` does what it should. If you *really* want to know *how*, you need to go binary. Otherwise use your valuable time to think about higher level problems.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Bit of a cheat, but if the task strictly relates to all forms of multiplication (rather than just the `*` operator), then divide by the reciprocal:

```
var result = first / (1 / (decimal)second);
```

Comment: You are going to want to cast that or you will get integer division on the `1 / second` and always get `0`.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: Only when first/second are typed as `int`, not decimal as stated, but tweaked anyway.

Comment: I assume first and second are both decimal, in which case that will be fine

Comment: most suitable answer to me :)

Comment: This is a particularly inefficient solution in terms of runtime speed.  Division is much slower than multiplication.

Comment: @Servy: Any implementation that doesn't just use `*` is pretty silly for all sorts of reasons. That's not really the point here.

Comment: @JonEgerton The language had to implement it somehow.  It didn't just magically appear implemented out of nowhere.  Understanding how it's implemented, or understanding another sufficiently appropriate algorithm for multiplication isn't a terrible thing to do for academic purposes.  Using it in a production application would be silly, yes.  This solution doesn't really add academic value.

Comment: What if `second` is zero?

Answer (score 6):

Just another way ;)

```
if (second < 0)
{ 
    second = Math.Abs(second);
    first = (-1) * first;
}
result = Enumerable.Repeat(first, second).Sum();
```

Comment: Repeat does not take decimal type parameters !

Comment: @Scorpion: Why do you need decimal? The first parameter can be a decimal type but the second parameter must be an integer because it's the multiplicator. But it must be >= 0, therefore i have edited my answer.

Comment: Ah, i haven't seen the `Want to multiply this for decimals...`. Point taken.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to multiple two decimals without using the * operator is to use the Decimal.Multiply method.

Example:

```
decimal first = -2.234M;
decimal second = 3.14M;

decimal product = Decimal.Multiply(first, second);
```

Comment: don't want to use * or .net inbuild Multiply. Want to implement my own logic. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Strictly with out '*' ? I'd take note of the XOR operator implemented. Although I know this code is not much different to the OP's.

```
int first = 2;
int second =2;
int result = 0;
bool isNegative;

isNegative = (first<0)^(second<0);

first = (first<0)?Math.Abs(first):first;    
second = (second<0)?Math.Abs(second):second;

for (int i = 1; i <= second; i++)
    result += first;

result = (isNegative)?-Math.Abs(result):result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach, using rules of logs, for the sake of completeness:

```
decimal result = (decimal)Math.Exp(
    Math.Log((double)third) + Math.Log((double)fourth));
```

It's not going to work for all decimals (in particular not for negative numbers, although it could be extended to detect these and work around them), but it's interesting nevertheless.